# PreparedStatement No Value Specified for Parameter One

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

Having issues with this the one that needs to be set is a auto increment integer so how would I Specify that

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `"+OnlineUsers.table2+"` VALUES (?,?,?)");

//What I do here
stmt.setInt(2, currentonline);
stmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(b.getTime()));
stmt.execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to specify the column names explicitly:

```
"INSERT INTO `" + OnlineUsers.table2 + "` (col2, col3) VALUES (?,?)"
```

Then:

```
stmt.setInt(1, currentonline);
stmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(b.getTime()));
```

This will make your code robust to the order of the columns changing in the database.

**Note**: If `OnlineUsers.table2` comes from an untrusted source you should validate this string, otherwise you could be at risk of an SQL injection attack.